# Show that: if $f \in \operatorname{Sp}(A)$, then the range of $f$ is finite, but the converse is not true.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The following is a question from: Rao, R.A., & Bhimasankaram, P. (2000). *Linear algebra*.

> Let $X$ be the set of all positive integers. In the vector space
> $\mathbb R^{X}$, what is the span of the set $A = \{f_i : i \geq 1\}$,
> where $f_i$ is the function in $\mathbb R^{X}$ taking value $1$ at $x = i$
> and $0$ elsewhere? Show that if $f \in \operatorname{Sp}(A)$, then the
> range of $f$ is finite but the converse is not true.

By definition of span:
$$
 \operatorname{Sp} A = \left\{ \sum_{i\in S} \alpha_i f_i : S \subseteq \mathbb X \land |S|\in X \land \alpha_i\in\mathbb R\right\} = \{f \in \mathbb R^X : \text{$f$ has finite range}\}
$$
where:
$$
\sum_{i\in S} \alpha_i f_i (x) = \alpha_x \quad \text{if $x\in S$, and 0 otherwise}
$$

It is obvious that any member in the span must have finite range, but I don't see why the converse is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1$ for all $x$.  Then the range of $f$ is $\{1\}$ which is a finite set. This does not belong to $Sp  A$ becasue $ g \in Sp A $ implies that $g(x)=0$ for all but finite number of $x$'s.

Answer (score 0):

$f\in\operatorname{sp}(A) $ iff $f=\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_if_i$ $\quad(|I|<\aleph_0) $

In other words $f\in \operatorname{sp}(A)$ iff $f(x) =0$ for all but finitely many $x\in\Bbb{Z}^+$.

Hence $f\in \operatorname{sp}(A) \implies \operatorname{range}(f)$ is finite.

But $\operatorname{range}(f)$ finite may not imply $f(x) =0$ for all but finitely many $x\in\Bbb{Z}^+$.

Counter example: $f\in\Bbb{R}^X$ with $0\notin \operatorname{range}(f)$ and $\operatorname{range}(f)$ is finite or $f(x) =0$ for finitely many $x\in\Bbb{Z}^+$

You can produce your own counter example now!